# Logger variable of log4j is always null

Tags: java, logging, log4j, web.xml

This is how I declared the variable

```
   final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);
```

my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

my log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/BMDashboard.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Logs file is being created but my logs (with logger.debug() and info() ) are not getting printed into the logs file. System logs are automatically getting printed.

logger variable is null.

[image]

but when I printed `System.out.println(Logger.getLogger(MainController.class));` I got org.apache.log4j.Logger@f7e9ad25

help me out on this, thanks

Comment: `logger` cannot be `null` - check with a debugger.

Comment: I checked with the debugger, it is null

Comment: `Logger.getLogger` will never return `null`. It simply cannot be the case that it is `null`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I have added a screenshot, please give it a look

Comment: And you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: no. I am not getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Well then it cannot be `null` now can it?

Comment: okay, I understood what you are saying. Then what does the null here signifies? and how can I get my code working?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I have updated the question again, will you please give it a look